# How to expose /Token End point from Startup.Auth.cs with Identity v2

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity-2

I am working with ASP.NET Identity 2 and trying to enable Token Authentication. From the Identity 2 sample there is nothing about Token Authentication so I setup myself by looking at different post. I am following the last answer of this post [app.UseOAuthBearerTokens with ASP.NET Identity 2.0's DbContext middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077447/app-useoauthbearertokens-with-asp-net-identity-2-0s-dbcontext-middleware/21861080#21861080)

and able to setup each and everything but now when I try to reach this end point on browser `http://localhost:6722/token` getting 404 error. Any idea?

Update:

Here is my ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider<TUserManager, TUser, TKey> : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
        where TUserManager : UserManager<TUser, TKey>
        where TUser : class, IUser<TKey>
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
        private readonly string _publicClientId;


        public ApplicationOAuthProvider(string publicClientId)
        {
            if (publicClientId == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("publicClientId");
            }


            _publicClientId = publicClientId;
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            var userManager = context.OwinContext.Get<TUserManager>(_publicClientId);

            TUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
            context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
            context.Validated(ticket);
            context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
        }

        public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
            {
                context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            // Resource owner password credentials does not provide a client ID.
            if (context.ClientId == null)
            {
                context.Validated();
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
        {
            if (context.ClientId == _publicClientId)
            {
                Uri expectedRootUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri, "/");

                if (expectedRootUri.AbsoluteUri == context.RedirectUri)
                {
                    context.Validated();
                }
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName)
        {
            IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {
                    "userName", userName
                }
            };
            return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
        }
    }
```

Here is my Startup.Oauth.cs

```
 public partial class Startup
    {

        static Startup()
        {
            PublicClientId = "self";
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider<ApplicationUserManager, User, int>(PublicClientId),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                AllowInsecureHttp = false
            };

        }
        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }
        public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }


        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and role manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDb.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            // Configure the sign in cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User, int>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                        getUserIdCallback: (claim) => int.Parse(claim.GetUserId()))

                }
            });



            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
            // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

            // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
            // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
            // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);



            // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
            //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
            //    clientId: "",
            //    clientSecret: "");

            //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
            //   consumerKey: "",
            //   consumerSecret: "");

            //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
            //   appId: "",
            //   appSecret: "");

            //app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
        }
    }
```

And I am trying to access /Token end point directly from the browser and it throws 404 error.

Comment: Code posted, Please take a look

Comment: Did u add Microsoft.Owin.System.Web and Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity.Owin packages from nuget?

Comment: Yeah, I think so, Please check this screen shot, https://www.dropbox.com/s/tb8vw82s43ffa26/screen.PNG Please let me know, if I missed any package as I created this from scratch. Did not use any startup template.

Comment: When you say that you are getting 404, are you sure you are using HTTP POST?

Comment: The authentication code sit inside startup.cs, so I am trying to accees it directly from the browser. In identity v1 this end point accessible directly from browser, so I am hoping to get something in response. What do you think?

Comment: The best article I've see so far: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/simple-oauth-server-implementing-a-simple-oauth-server-with-katana-oauth-authorization-server-components-part-1

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue today, what fixed the problem for me was installing the following Nuget package.

I have no idea why it wasn't installed with all of the other packages, but give it a shot and let us know.

The package name is `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`

Comment: Thanks for your attention on this. I have this package installed, in my case, there is something wrong when I was creating new object OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions..Previously, I set the flag for AllowInsecureHttp to false, I just turn this flag to true and everything started work for me.

Comment: i have it installed. but reinstalling it solves the problem. saved me from hair loss. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Do you have the other part of Startup class? Because you should have a Startup.cs file in your web project that is calling your ConfigureAuth method. If not you will get a 404 exception. The startup.cs file should look like this:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(YOUR_NAME_SPACE_TO_THE_STARTUP_FILE.Startup))]
namespace YOUR_NAME_SPACE_TO_THE_STARTUP_FILE
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

If you then trying to access the page through your browser you should get this error:

```
{
    error: "unsupported_grant_type"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case I wrapped the `AllowInsecureHttp` in an `#if DEBUG` processor directive, and ended up publishing it to the server (as Release) and my customer didn't afford SSL.
After removing the `DEBUG` condition it all works fine now.

Comment: Spent last hour trying to figure out what-a-heck-is-wrong with it. Silly me!

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a similar (if not same) issue where I was getting 404s when accessing `/token`. Eventually worked out that it was due to the order I was calling things in the Startup.Configuration method. I was calling `ConfigureAuth(app)` at the very bottom of this method, after I had added Ninject config (ie. `app.UseNinjectMiddleware(CreateKernel).UseNinjectWebApi(config);`. Moving the `ConfigureAuth` above the Ninject setup fixed this issue and `/token` now works.